# How to post the data to server in android?

Tags: java, android

Hi i want to post the data to php server i have a parmeters like

```
parameters:upid,product_id,pname,pquantity,price,pickup_date,pickup_time,name,email,mobile,address,location,pincode,total_amount
```

i call the asyncTask in my Activity class

```
PlaceOrderTask placeOrderTask = new PlaceOrderTask(YourBasket.this,upid,"2", iconName,"200", "250.00", dateFormat,timeFormat, name,email,mobileNo,"Hyderbad",location, "500032", totalAmount);
placeOrderTask.execute();
```

in My AsyncTask i will Call Like this

```
          public class PlaceOrderTask extends AsyncTask 
        {
                String upid, product_id, productName, productQuantity, pprice, date, time,
                        name, email, mobileNo, location, address, pincode, totalAmount;
                private ProgressDialog pd = null;
                Context context;
                public PlaceOrderTask(Context context,String upid, String product_id, String productName,
                        String productQuantity, String pprice, String date, String time,
                        String name, String email, String mobileNo, String location,
                        String address, String pincode, String totalAmount) 
                {
                    this.context = context;
                    this.upid = upid;
                    this.product_id = product_id;
                    this.productName = productName;
                    this.productQuantity = productQuantity;
                    this.pprice = pprice;
                    this.date = date;
                    this.time = time;
                    this.name = name;
                    this.email = email;
                    this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
                    this.location = location;
                    this.address =address;
                    this.pincode =pincode;
                    this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
                    }

@Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
    {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pd.setMessage("Please Wait.....");

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

        pd.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
    }
```

what we call in doInBackground and onPostExcute

```
and Here My url is like this
http://safewash.docni.in/iosapp/order.php
```

This is MyProblem guys can any one suggest me how we can do this

Comment: Please read about the asynctask before use that in application, Do google it you will get more tutorial

Comment: shouldn't you be sending the data as a JSON object?

Comment: s i am using json data only

Comment: ok let me give you an example then.

Comment: Read my answer. It is much more comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

Async Task for Post-type requests:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class WebPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    private String url = null;
    private int id;
    private OnResponseListener listener;
    private String jsonString;
    private String header = null;
    private String headerKey;

    public WebPostAsyncTask(String url, int id, OnResponseListener listener, String jsonString)
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.id = id;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.jsonString = jsonString;
    }

    public WebPostAsyncTask(String url, int id, OnResponseListener listener, String jsonString, String header, String headerKey)
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.id = id;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.jsonString = jsonString;
        this.header = header;
        this.headerKey = headerKey;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

            if (header != null)
            {
                httpPost.addHeader(headerKey, header);
            }

            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonString, "UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            return response;
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (listener != null)
        {
            listener.onResponse(id, result);
        }
    }

    public interface OnResponseListener
    {
        public void onResponse(int id, String response);
    }

}
```

To use it in your Activity:

```
public class TrialActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final int URL_ID = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        try
        {
            jObject.put("data1", "trial_data1");
            jObject.put("data2", "trial_data1");
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
        }
        new WebPostAsyncTask("YOUR_URL_HERE", URL_ID, listener, jObject.toString()).execute();
    }

    private OnResponseListener listener = new OnResponseListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(int id, String response)
        {

            switch (id)
            {
            case URL_ID:
                // You will get your service response here
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The code is pretty straightforward, if you still face any issues drop me a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [jsoup library](http://jsoup.org/download).

Example:

```
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
                public void run() {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://your.url/ping").get().data("user",user ,"pwd" ,pwd).timeout(3000);
                                        Element head = doc.head();
                                        Element body = doc.body();
        final String s = head.text() + body.text();
}
    }).run();
```